# Kotlin using two readln but only the first one get the input

Tags: kotlin

I using kotlin to get two lines of input

```
val number1 = readln()
val number2 = readln()
println(" number 1 is $number1 number 2 is $number2")
```

Result is :

```
1
1
number 1 is 1 number 2 is
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. If we add a println in between the `readln`s then code works fine. Might be a bug

Comment: Seems issue with Intellij, fixed in next version https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951/Console-readLine-skips-input-in-202211